# Can I use WAL mode in SQLite3 if I use an additional mutex for multiple writers?

Tags: c++, sqlite, mutex, wal

http://sqlite.org/wal.html

WAL mode is specified for N readers and one writer. It the writer's identity interchangible? For example, I have N writers and an additional mutex. Each writer has to obtain this mutex to be able to write, so there are never two writers writing at the same time. Is this possible? And if so, why is this not part of SQLite since to me, it appears to be a natural extension of the WAL mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WAL mode, it is not possible to have multiple active writers.
However, it is possible for multiple writers to *attempt* to write.
This conflict is handled in exactly the same way as in rollback journal mode, i.e., the first writer locks the database, and the others have to wait.

Comment: Just to clarify: Am I fine to use a PC-wide mutex for writing? Can I have an arbitrary number of writers then, because the mutex guarantees that there is no simultaneous write?

Comment: If you use your own mutex, it essentially *replaces* the SQLite locking mechanism.